# How to increase the size of my tableview cell

Tags: ios, swift

I am new to iOS development and have difficulty in making the `label` of `tableview cell` display properly.

I have set proper `constraints` but the last `label` gets `hidden`.

I am adding the screenshots below. Please guide me on how to solve this.

As you can see the `label` below the Date `label` gets hidden. All of these is embedded in a view. Link [2]

and hence in the output the `label` gets hidden. Link [3]

Comment: show the constraints you have added on both labels

Comment: increase the height of cell, I think this can be fix your issue

Comment: @emrcftci tried that but not working

Comment: @Surjeet added the constraint pic

Comment: check my answer please

Answer (score 1):

You can use this :

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 100 //return whatever you want
}
```

**Important :**

1)You must set your viewController as : `class yourViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate`

2)Give your tableView delegates to `self` :

```
yourTableView.delegate = self
```

Hope it helps...

Comment: Thanks but I did it by setting my label constraints and it worked

Answer (score 0):

That's probably something wrong with your constraint.

Make sure constrained your labels from `Top to Bottom` as shown in the [image]